# Save File Dialogue Box in Ubuntu 20.04 Doesn't Show "Recent"?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, nautilus, desktop-environments, filemanager

Although browsers have a default save directory, but we don't always want to save things in the default directory especially at times when we are certain as to what we are downloading and why. In such cases, if we know the file being downloaded, we often want to save it to a particular specific location other than the default.

Also, the browsers mostly have an option to allow the user to download to a particular location (the "Ask location before download" option). **But, I have realised that Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't like to show the "Recents" tab in the "Save File" dialogue box**. This would mean that every time I download something important that I am unlikely to throw away, and would like to keep for a longer time, I have to dig deep into my folders to tell the browser where to download the file (especially when I am downloading files to a specific set of locations; Ubuntu does by default open the last used location in the "Save" dialogue), and will often end up wasting more time fishing out the download folder than what it took me to find the file!.

Having the "Recent" Tab in the dialogue would be quite helpful. Is there a solution to my problem? Can I tweak some settings / .conf files or something to get the "Recents" tab?

---

UPDATE:
What I realised is that **even the Save dialogue for saving new files (created locally) doesn't show the "Recents" tab which is very annoying!**

---

UPDATE:
[What Controls the System's Save Dialogue Box, and File Selector Dialogue Box?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294338/what-controls-the-systems-save-dialogue-box-and-file-selector-dialogue-box)

Comment: AFAIK the **Recent** view is for recently used **files** and *not* directories. So, it is not meaningful for **Save As** dialog where directories are shown.

Comment: "Recents" --> Right click on item --> "Open Item Location " helps a lot @FedonKadifeli

Comment: Yes. I understand your use case and it seems perfectly valid... However, I don't think that GNOME developers are so far-sighted! :)